# Re-sampling rows from two columns in R

Tags: r, simulation, resampling

I have a data set of 2 columns (say X and Y). i need to generate 100 samples of both columns with replacement  where each sample has 10 rows.

The X and Y values should be related. That means basically i need to re sample rows.

This is my work so far to generate 1 sample,

```
set.seed(326581)
X1=rnorm(10,0,1)
Y1=rnorm(10,0,2)
data=data.frame(X1,Y1)
library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
sample_n(data,10,replace = T)
```

since i need 100 samples, i tried the replicate function in R. But it didnt work. So i tried to use a loop.

```
rex=c()
 rey=c()
 for(i in 1:100)
 {
 rex[i]=sample_n(data,10,replace=T)[,1]
 rey[i]=sample_n(data,10,replace=T)[,2]

 }
```

but it didnt give the desired output.

Can anyone help me to figure out the error ? 
or is there any function (like replicate function to sampling from 1 column) to this in much more easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

**Using base R's `sample`**

```
# Sample 100 rows from data
set.seed(2017)
idx <- sample(nrow(data), 100, replace = T)

# Store samples in a 100x2 data.frame 
df.smpl <- data[idx, ]
```

**Using `dplyr::sample_n`**

```
set.seed(2017)
df.smpl <- data %>%
    sample_n(100, replace = T)
```

Both methods will store 100 samples drawn (with replacement) from the rows of `data` in a new `data.frame` of dimension

```
dim(data.smpl)
#[1] 100   2
```

Or if you prefer samples to be in a `list` of vectors

```
lapply(idx, function(i) as.numeric(data[i, ]))
```

---

### Update

To repeat drawing 10 rows from `data` 100 times you can use `replicate`

```
set.seed(2017);
lst <- replicate(
    100,
    df.smpl <- data %>% sample_n(10, replace = T),
    simplify = FALSE)
```

This generates a `list` with 100 `data.frame`s

```
length(lst)
[1] 100
```

each with dimension `10x2`

```
sapply(lst, dim)
#[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#[1,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97] [,98]
#[1,]    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
#[2,]     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
#[,99] [,100]
#[1,]    10     10
#[2,]     2      2
```

Comment: HI Thank you for your reply. But in your answer you have sampled 100 rows. isnt it ? that is not i want. I need " 100 samples  " where each sample has generated by sampling rows (that is why i used "sample_n " command under dplyr package instead of using the "sample" command.) . So in my final out put there should be 100 samples where each sample has 2 columns .

Comment: @Statlover *"So in my final out put there should be 100 samples where each sample has 2 columns "* That's exactly what my solution gives. Also `sample_n` is just a wrapper around `sample.int` and does the same as `sample`. You can see that in both the base R and `dplyr` solution `df.smpl` is the same.

Comment: My bad. I haven't included the sample size of the each sample. the sample size should be 10 . So there should be 100 samples where  each sample should be 10 in size(by sampling rows). Is it possible to edit your answer to reflect ? Thank you.

Comment: @Statlover So how should your expected output look? (1) A single `1000x2` `data.frame` (`1000` because of `10x100` samples); or (2) a list with `100` `data.frame`s, each of which has dimension `10x2`?

Comment: i need a list with 100 data.frames, each of which has dimension 10x2. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. Can this be done directly be using any "apply" function ?

Comment: @Statlover `replicate` is already an optimised `*apply`-like loop; so I'm not sure why you want another "apply" loop. Sure you could use `lapply`, but it would be an unnecessarily convoluted way.

Comment: @Statlover PS. To see what `replicate` does, just type in `replicate` in an R terminal. You will see that `replicate` is nothing but an `sapply` loop.

Comment: Yeah, i got you. Thank you. If you have time, please refer this question and see what you can do . [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276653/convert-columns-in-a-list-to-a-data-frame-in-r