# Convert columns in a list to a data frame in R

Tags: r, simulation

I have the following list that created using R,

```
set.seed(326581)
X1=rnorm(10,0,1)
Y1=rnorm(10,0,2)
data=data.frame(X1,Y1)

lst <- replicate(
  100,
  df.smpl <- data %>% sample_n(10, replace = T),
  simplify = FALSE)
```

this list represents 100 samples where each sample has 2 columns (X,Y) with a sample size of 10.

I need to separate all the X columns into one data frame and Y columns into one data frame.  So finally i should have 2 data frames each have 100 columns and 10 rows.

I tried this loop ,

```
new1=c()
new2=c()
for(i in 1:100)
{
  new1[i]=lst[[i]]$X
  new2[i]=lst[[i]]$Y
}
```

But it is not working. Can anyone tell me to figure out the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`, where we `transpose` the object to a `list` of 'X1's and 'Y1s' separately and then bind the columns within in `map` to create a `list` of `tibble`s

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- transpose(lst) %>% 
              map(bind_cols)
```

It is better to keep it in a `list`, but if we want separate objects

```
outx <- out[[1]]
outy <- out[[2]]
dim(outx)
#[1]  10 100
dim(outy)
#[1]  10 100
```

---

Or do an extraction with `lapply` from `base R`

```
data.frame(lapply(lst, `[`, 'X1'))
data.frame(lapply(lst, `[`, 'Y1'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I am having a little knowledge about R data types. I need the final answer  in the data type  similar to that generate by following code   `replicate(n=10 , rnorm(30,0,1))` . Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Just wrap it with `as.matrix`

Answer (score 2):

Using `do.call` `cbind`, concat them into one dataframe , then we split the dataframe to get the expected out put

```
s=do.call("cbind", lst)
Y=s[,seq(2,200,2)]
X=s[,seq(1,200,2)]
```